Why is there no sp-back edge indicated between two specific nodes in this DJ Graph?
I am reading the paper Identifying Loops Using DJ Graphs by Sreedhar et al. In this paper, they present the following classification of edges in a depth first search ordering of a graph (specifically a DJ graph, but the distinction is not too important for this question).

sp-back edge, if y = x or y is an ancestor of x in the spanning tree
sp-tree edge, if x is the parent of y in the spanning tree
sp-forward edge, if x is an ancestor but not the parent of y in the spanning tree
sp-cross edge, if x and y have no ancestor-descendant relationship.

There is a motivating example of the DFS ordering of a graph in the paper which I have linked below.

For the purposes of this question, we can ignore the distinction between the dotted and solid edges.
Based on the DFS numbering, the spanning tree comes out to be:
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9
                         +--> 6

The sp-back edges are indicated by a bubble at their source node ends. So, 7->3, 4->3, 5->1 are sp-back edges.
My question is: why isn't 9->5 indicated as an sp-back edge? It satisfies the criteria for the sp-back edge, namely, node 5 being an ancestor of node 9 (5->7->8->9 in the spanning tree).
I've written some throwaway code to classify the edges following the criteria set out in this paper, and it matches my reasoning. 9->5 is classified as an sp-back edge by my code.
Any pointers would be most welcome.
EDIT: For determining ancestor relationships, I have used the logic outlined in this SO post (comparing discovery start and end times).

I suspect it's just an oversight in making the figure. You could argue that only immediate ancestors qualify for an sp-back edge but then 7->3 and 5->1 wouldn't be marked as such. So it's definitely transitive.

The text isn't really clear about what "y is an ancestor of x in the spanning tree" means.  In this case, it doesn't mean you see y before you see x.  Rather it means that you found the node x while you were in the process of searching for all of y's children.
After "5", we look at "6", and we're done with "5".  We don't investigate "1" because we've already been there.  So even though we visit "9" later, we don't visit it because of "5".

See comment below.  I am completely wrong.  I missed the edge from 5->7.

After 5, we look at 6, then we hit a dead end. Then we look at other unvisited outgoing nodes from 5; the only one we find is 7 (1 is already visited), and from there on, 8 and 9. So, in my understanding, 5 is still on the "DFS stack" when we hit 9 (the stack being [8,7,5,4,3,2,1,0]).

You're right.  I missed the edge from 5 -> 7.  I agree with you.  9->5 is a back edge.  Maybe there's a bug in the book?  Have you checked the errata.

It's a paper. I've searched " errata" and some related combinations, but have drawn a blank.
